# C# GridView - Combobox Column with nullable data

Tags: c#, silverlight, gridview, combobox, radgridview

I'm trying to create a RadGridView that is populated by a call to a WCF that return a query that includes some null values. I need for one of these values, an integer describing 'Roles', to be the only writeable field, accessed through a combobox column. I need to have the combobox display the same 4 choices in the dropdown, regardless if the value is not, but labeled with a string that is *not* apart of the query results.

All the other columns are read-only and could be automatically generated, but I want to apply some custom formatting based on the value of the 'Roles' field.

I'm making the WCF call and setting RadGridView.ItemSource to the result in the code-behind.

```
private void ExpandGet(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{ GetContent(4, CurrentUser.Id); }

private void GetContent(int libType, int userId)
{
    Services.Libraries.Do(d1 => Dispatcher.ExecuteSync(
          () =>
          {
              var res = d1.EndGetRole(d1.BeginGetRole(userId, libType, null, null));
              return res;
          },
      init: () => WaitContent1.IsBusy = true,
      result: res =>
      {
          Content1.ItemsSource = res;
      },
      finalize: ok1 => WaitContent1.IsBusy = false));
}
```

I tried creating a separate list for the Roles column to use for its DisplayMember Path, and add that to the Autogenerated DataGrid, but it doesn't add anything and returns a blank grid.

```
public class RIdName
    {
        public int RId { get; set; }
        public string RName { get; set; }
    }                       

    public List<IdName> RItemsSource;

    public void SetGridUp()
    {

        RItemsSource.Add(new IdName {RId = -1, RName = "None"});
        RItemsSource.Add(new IdName {RId = 0, RName = "User"});
        RItemsSource.Add(new IdName {RId = 1, RName = "Contributer"});
        RItemsSource.Add(new IdName {RId = 2, RName = "Manager"});

        GridViewComboBoxColumn column = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
        column.DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Role");
        column.DisplayMemberPath = "Rname";
        column.Header = "My Column";
        column.UniqueName = "MyColumn";
        column.ItemsSource = RItemsSource;
        Content1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        Content1.Columns.Add(column);
    }
```

I also tried to do it through XAML andchange the DisplayMemberPath from there, but since the strings that I need to display are not in the original query and ItemSource I have nothing to set it to. In the table I get the integer values but no choices at all in the dropdown.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Content1"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
     CanUserInsertRows="False">
 <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LibraryName}"     UniqueName="Name" />
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Per}" UniqueName="Per" />
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding By}" UniqueName="By" />
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding On}" UniqueName="On" IsReadOnly="True" />
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Role} DisplayMemberBinding="IdName" UniqueName="Role" />
 </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>  
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Finally, I need to use this Grid with the same query but for different content type in about 15 different grids on the page. I would ideally like to create a template of some kind and reuse it.

What approach should I take to deal with this combobox column? I tried using a converter (which calls a WCF service) but I just got back the integers and no dropdown selections. I need the column to show the actually values, and I want to be able to define the dropdown choices somewhere in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close with trying to do it through XAML, it's something I do often.  What you need to do is bind it to a property in the ViewModel using the ItemsSource property of the GridViewComboBoxItem.  To do that, you'll need to set a reference to the ViewModel as a StaticResource.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Key="mainPageViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Role"
        DataMemberBinding="{Binding RID}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RItemSource, Source={StaticResource mainPageViewModel}}"
        DisplayMemberPath="RName"
        SelectedValueMemberPath="RID" />
```

You can find some more info here if needed.
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/troubleshooting/blank-cells

Comment: I got so frustrated with this that I left it out. Came back to it a few months later and this link help me solve it. I'm not using a view model on these pages, just traditional code-behind, but assigning the ItemsSource in the code behind and leaving the XAML as `code` ItemsSource="{Binding}" `code` did the trick. Thanks Mitchell.